# Disable entering new address in billing information

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I disable entering new address in billing information in checkout?
Is this a setting somewhee?

I want that customer can only have the address he entered before or changed it in customer area. In checkout the customer shouldn't be allowed to change the address.

Thank you very much.